MacOS проблема переустановки ОС
Отформатировал жёсткий диск на маке и решил перезаписать операционную систему. При установки ОС я прошёл этап восстановления через интернет и мне предложили установить версию Sierra. Принял предложенную систему и прохожу этап установки, ползунок установки идет до конца и в конце выдаёт ошибку "при подготовке к установке произошла ошибка попробуйте повторить запуск этой программы mac os sierra"
Перерыл весь интернет и не нашёл способ как это пофиксить. Кто сталкивался с этой проблемой и есть ли какой то способ это починить без участия мастера из сервиса?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

sierra же вроде лет 8 назад была и давно не поддерживается

@user7860670 забыл упомянуть о самом устройстве. Мак 2016 года модель 1707

it just works https://mrmacintosh.com/fixed-an-error-occurred-while-preparing-the-installation-macos-sierra-recovery-error/ Фигасе там танцы с бубном

@user7860670 мне уже терять нечего, буду танцевать. Мне нужно оживить кирпич))))
